# question regarding javascript;Html generation and search current webpage for tags

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I have 3 questions, if you have for example this simple website

```
<html> <head> </head> <body> <table>
<tr> <td><a
href="http://www.hello1.com">www.hello1.com</a></td>
</tr> <tr> <td><a
href="http://www.hello2.com">www.hello2.com</a></td>
</tr> </table> </html>
```

**Question 1)**

If I for instance decide to click on link number 2 (www.hello2.com), Is this stored in some kind of variable?

I know that this is storing the current URL but not the one that you click

```
window.location.href;
```

**Question 2)**
How do you search your document, say that I would like to search the this website and store all the links in a javascript array like this

```
    var myArray = [];

searchThisWebSiteForURLS()//Do this function that I don't know to write that search this htmlsite for url's

var myArray = [ 'http://www.hello1.com', 'http://www.hello2.com'];//This is the reslt after that the function has been executed
```

**Question 3)**
I would like to write out these links. Say that I have another table like this

```
 <html> <head> </head> <body> <table>
    <tr> <td><a
    href="X">X</a></td>
    </tr> <tr> <td><a
    href="Y"></a>Y</td>
    </tr> </table> </html>

Where X = http://www.hello1.com
And Y = http://www.hello2.com
```

Of course it shall be as many rows as there are elements in the array like this

```
 <html> <head> </head> <body> <table>
    <tr> <td><a href="X">X</a></td></tr>
    <tr> <td><a href="Y"></a>Y</td></tr>
    <tr> <td><a href="Z">Z</a></td></tr>
    <tr> <td><a href="A">A</a></td></tr>
    <tr> <td><a href="B">B</a></td></tr>
    </table> </html>
```

Where Z, A, B are the elements 3,4,5 in the array

```
 var myArray = [ 'http://www.hello1.com', 'http://www.hello2.com','http://www.hello3.com','http://www.hello4.com','http://www.hello5.com'];
```

EDIT!--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Wow really thanks, all of you, really thanks! I just have one more question regarding the links, when comparing two links, say that the array looks like this

```
var pageLinks = ['http://www.example.at', 'http://www.example2.at', 'http://www.someothersite.at'];
```

And say that the user has pressed the example "http://www.example.at" link, then I want to create the table containing the similar links. So I do something like this

```
function checkForSimilarLink(theLinkToCompareWith){// in this case theLinkToCompareWith = "http://www.example.at"
    var numLinks = pageLinks.length;

    for(var i = 0; i < numLinks; i++) {
       //Check if numLinks[i]== theLinkToCompareWith* 
    }
}
```

So how would you write this compare function? In this case we can consider

"http://www.example.at" and "http://www.example1.at" the "same" while "http://www.someothersite.at" obviosly aren't

Thanks again :)

Comment: you wouldn't want to store URLs in Arrays in JS, this is bad for SEO. There are jQuery plugins that will do page searching for you.

Comment: The thing is that this isn't of concern, this site will not be on the web, it will be on a LAN and it will only be act as a "redirection page" this page will only be used everytime someone clicks on a link. But thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

I didn't understand question 1, but here's something for question 2 and 3:

Question 2:

```
var pageLinks  = []; 
var anchors    = document.getElementsByTagName('a'); 
var numAnchors = anchors.length; 
for(var i = 0; i < numAnchors; i++) {
    pageLinks.push(anchors[i].href);
}
//now pageLinks holds all your URLs
```

Question 3:

```
// say pageLinks holds your desired URLs
var pageLinks = ['http://www.example.at', 'http://www.example2.at', 'http://www.example3.at'];

// create an empty table
var table     = document.createElement('table');

// ... and it's tbody
var tbody     = document.createElement('tbody'); 

// loop through your URLs
var numLinks = pageLinks.length; 
for(var i = 0; i < numLinks; i++) {

    // create new table row...
    var tr   = document.createElement('tr');

    // a cell...
    var td   = document.createElement('td');

    // and your anchor...
    var a    = document.createElement('a'); 

    // set the anchor's href
    a.setAttribute('href', pageLinks[i]);
    // set the anchor's text, it's also the URL in this example
    a.innerHTML = pageLinks[i]; 

    // append the anchor to the table cell
    td.appendChild(a);

    // ... and that cell to the new row
    tr.appendChild(td);

    // ... and that row to the tbody, right? ;-) 
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
}

// after all rows were added to the tbody, 
// append tbody to the table
table.appendChild(tbody);

// and finally append this table to any existing 
// element in your document, e.g. the body: 
document.body.appendChild(table);

// ...or add it to a div for example: 
//document.getElementById('anyDiv').appendChild(table);
```

Answer (score 0):

Go study JQuery!!!! XDD The best for web development.

for the first and second question in with jquery:

```
var anchors = $('a'); //returns all <a></a> elements from here you can get the url from all of theam
```

With jquery u can write any element that you want.

```
var table = $('<table></table>');
var tr = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo(table);
var td = $('<td></td>').setText('your link here')appendTo(tr);
```

. . .

table.appendTo(The parent element to add the table);

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1:**
You can capture the onclick event for clicking on the link and during that store whatever information you want to a variable of your choosing (though, this would only be relevant if you included `return false` in the onclick event because the link would otherwise take the user to a new page and end your session).

Question 2 and 3 were answered quite well by Alex.